# ListView.ScrollTo not working properly with HasUnevenRows property. Possible Bug

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Whe using the Xamarin.Forms ListView.ScrollTo function with HasUnevenRows = "true" some large items appears cut at the bottom, the scroll function is working well because the scroll works but the large items are not fully scrolled, only half of the item is scrolled and you can move the rest with the finger. When changed to "false" the items are showed ok. Like this:

[image]

This is my code for scrolling:

```
vm.ListMessages.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
   var target = vm.ListMessages[vm.ListMessages.Count - 1];
   MessagesListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
}
```

And this is my XAML (only the ListView... is large)

```
<ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListMessages}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" IsEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" ItemTapped="MessagesListView_ItemTapped" SelectionMode="None" VerticalOptions="End"/>
```

I think this is a bug because is in the official buglist https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/28/28277/bug.html but this is old and I think this should be solved.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: **some large items appears cut ad the bottom.** What it means? I set HasUnevenRows = "true" ,it will just change listview row height. Can you post the screenshot about your problem here?

Comment: hi, added a picture for better explanation

Comment: Can you provide your sample here, I will test it at my side.

Comment: Hi code is large, depends on many files... hard to share here

Comment: Just providing some code about screenshot here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!...

Problem was in the picture updating... when the item is added the picture is not yet loaded and the scroll works well, but, after some milliseconds the picture is loaded into the control and need to scroll because it's size changed and goes out of screen.. I needed to add this event to the image:

```
        OutCellImage.SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            do scroll...
        };
```